# Sorting data from database with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I suspect my question is stupid and answer is obvious, but I TOTALLY stuck with it.

In controller `movies_controller.rb` I have method `index`, which fills the array `@movies` with values from database by calling `@movies = Movie.all`, and method `sort`, which do almost the same, but use `@movies = Movie.order(:title)` instead.

If I call `sort` explicitly from `index` what I see in View `Index.html.haml` is sorted by title list of movies as I expect. But, how can I call method `sort` by clicking on link? I try

In Index.html.haml:

```
%th= link_to 'Movies title', 'movies', :on_click => 'self.sort'
```

In routes.rb:

```
match ":controller => movies, :action => sort" => 'movies/index'
```

and nothing is happening, method `sort` never executes. Actually, I have no idea how to do it right. Looks like it is obvious for everyone, but me.

Can I find short answer how to do it right? Please, kick me in right direction!

Comment: You should always use the `order` argument when possible. Fetching all records, sorting and paginating them is usually very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for sorting data in table then you need some plug in to in place sort the table according to some attribute. following jquery plugin help you to do that,

https://github.com/linjunpop/jquery-tablesorter-rails

or you can achieve the same with background sorting with order clause. check out the following,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching! I felt that solution is simple! Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

For quick and easy you can use 'ransack' gem.
For some writing by yourself check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns